# How can I resolve an error in Targetpath?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am developing a small script that creates a chrome shortcut.
I want to have Facebook as homepage when this shortcut is used so I thought I could just append "www.facebook.com" to the `target` variable that is fed to `shortcut.Targetpath`, but I get an error. Here is my code snippet

```
desktop = winshell.desktop()
path = os.path.join(desktop, "Chrome.lnk")
target = r'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe ' '"www.facebook.com'
wDir = r"%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application"
icon = r"%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

shell = Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(path)
shortcut.Targetpath = target
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = wDir
shortcut.IconLocation = icon
shortcut.save()
```

and the IDE shows the following error:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 581, in __setattr__
    raise AttributeError("Property '%s.%s' can not be set." % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Property '<unknown>.Targetpath' can not be set.
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `Targetpath` should contain an *executable path*, you shouldn't add the default homepage to that variable.
To have Chrome open a default webpage you should use the `shortcut.Arguments`  which is what you're actually missing and you should fix `shortcut.TargetPath`.
So you should modify your code along the following lines:

```
target = r'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
arguments = r'https://www.facebook.com'
```

and then

```
shortcut.Targetpath = target
shortcut.Arguments = arguments
```

In my answer, I assume all the rest is correct.  Maybe you will need to modify a bit `target` and `wDir`.